# Infinite loop when writing blank records to a binary file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

The purpose of the following short program is to search through a binary file (that contains details of different trains) for a particular train (whose number is accepted from the user) and then rewrite a blank record at that location.

That is, I wish to 'delete' that train record.

The problem is that the program goes into an infinite loop and repeatedly writes blank records to the binary file, thereby resulting in an enormous 2 GB .dat file being created.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>

struct train {
    int train_no;
    char train_name[50], source[20], dest[20];
    int n_AC1, n_AC2, n_ACC, n_FC, n_SLC, n_SS; // variables for no of seats 
    train() { //default constructor
        train_no = 0;
        n_AC1=0, n_AC2=0, n_ACC=0, n_FC=0, n_SLC=0, n_SS=0;
        strcpy(train_name, "/0");
        strcpy(source, "/0");
        strcpy(dest, "/0");
    }
    //member functions to accept and display the above values
};

void remove_train(fstream &f) {
    train t, blank;
    int tno, found = 0;
    do {
        cout<<"Enter the train no: ";
        cin>>tno;
        if(tno <=0)
            cout<<"Invalid train number. Please re-enter."<<endl;
    }
    while(tno <=0);
    f.seekg(0L, ios::beg);
    f.read((char*)&t, sizeof(train));
    while(!f.eof() && !found) {
        if(t.train_no == tno) {
            found = 1;
            f.seekp(-sizeof(train), ios::cur);
            f.write((char*)&blank, sizeof(train));
            cout<<"Train number "<<tno<<" has been deleted!"<<endl;
        }
        else
            f.read((char*)&t, sizeof(train));
    }
    if(found == 0)
        cout<<"ERROR: train not found."<<endl;
}

int main() {
    fstream f("Trains.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    remove_train(f);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

When the above program is executed, after I input the train number as '1', the only observable output is "Train number 1 has been deleted", following which the program goes into the aforementioned infinite loop.

This doesn't seem to be an isolated issue; whenever I try to move back by one record and 
then write a blank record anywhere in the Railway Reservation project that this code is a part of, the same problem ensues. For instance, if it is a passenger record I wish to overwrite, this is the relevant code fragment that seems to be causing the issue:

```
f.seekp(-1L*sizeof(passenger), ios::cur);
f.write((char*)&p, sizeof(passenger));
```

MAJOR EDIT: The problem was fixed when I replaced -sizeof(train) with -110L (which *is* the byte size of the 'train' structure)! Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: I find the `while(!f.eof()...)` *highly* suspect.

Comment: Don't know if this will solve, but your initialization of the `struct train` seems wrong at the `strcpy`: You should type `strcpy(train_name, "\0");` instead of `strcpy(train_name, "/0");`. This happens at the other two `strcpy` commands after this.

Comment: C++ is like Zombieland, only more brutal. Hence rule #17: always doublecheck your exit conditions

Comment: When you reach the statement `found = 1;` the loop should be left. You should try to use a debugger, to look at the variables and the program flow. Setting a breakpoint at the point I mentiond should help.

Comment: ^I tried using the break statement after I write the blank record, but the problem persists. And apologies if I sound naive, but how do I use a debugger? The IDE I'm using is Dev C++, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I must say I am at a loss to find a fault in your code. I've run a copy of it and it worked as expected.

There are a few minor errors (for instance it will fail if your data file does not exist) and the code could certainly be improved (your usage of f.eof() is somewhat awkward), but nothing that can explain the behaviour you're describing.

Here is the exact version I'm running right now. Except for a bit of extra code to create a dummy data file and a few debug outputs, I don't see any difference with yours.

Maybe you could try to compile it and see if it fails in your environment?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct train {
    int train_no;
    char train_name[50], source[20], dest[20];
    int n_AC1, n_AC2, n_ACC, n_FC, n_SLC, n_SS; // variables for no of seats 
    train() { //default constructor
        train_no = 0;
        n_AC1=0, n_AC2=0, n_ACC=0, n_FC=0, n_SLC=0, n_SS=0;
        strcpy(train_name, "");
        strcpy(source, "");
        strcpy(dest, "");
    }
    //member functions to accept and display the above values
};

void remove_train(fstream &f) {
    train t, blank;
    int tno, found = 0;
    do {
        cout<<"Enter the train no: ";
        cin>>tno;
        if(tno <=0)
            cout<<"Invalid train number. Please re-enter."<<endl;
    }
    while(tno <=0);
    cout<<"deleting train "<<tno<<endl;
    f.seekg(0L, ios::beg);
    f.read((char*)&t, sizeof(train));
    while(!f.eof() && !found) {
cout<<f.tellp()<<endl;
        if(t.train_no == tno) {
            found = 1;
            f.seekp(-sizeof(train), ios::cur);
cout<<"delete "<<f.tellp()<<"/"<<f.tellg()<<endl;
            f.write((char*)&blank, sizeof(train));
            cout<<"Train number "<<tno<<" has been deleted!"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
cout<<"read "<<f.tellg()<<endl;
            f.read((char*)&t, sizeof(train));
        }
    }
    if(found == 0)
        cout<<"ERROR: train not found."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"done"<<endl;
}

void create_trains(int n)
{
    fstream f("Trains.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
    train t;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
    {
        t.train_no = i;
        f.write((char*)&t, sizeof(train));
    }

}
int main() {
    create_trains (10);
    fstream f("Trains.dat", ios::binary | ios::in | ios::out);
    remove_train(f);
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: hmm yes, your code works fine! And even more puzzlingly, the problem I mentioned was fixed when I replaced -sizeof(train) with -110L (which is actually the byte size of the 'train' structure)! Any idea why that's the case?